# How to subtract time in each row R

Tags: r, date, row, intervals, subtraction

I am using R studio in mac. I have defined `df` as the following. Can anyone help me to calculate time interval for each row?

```
> df                       
                       V1                  V1.1
1   "2016-05-12 07:28:11" "2016-05-12 07:58:47"
2   "2016-05-12 07:27:39" "2016-05-12 07:58:22"
3   "2016-05-12 07:19:22" "2016-05-12 07:49:40"
4   "2016-05-12 07:15:12" "2016-05-12 07:47:08"
5   "2016-05-12 07:26:44" "2016-05-12 07:58:24"
6   "2016-05-12 07:27:53" "2016-05-12 07:58:33"
7   "2016-05-12 07:20:20" "2016-05-12 07:53:19"
8   "2016-05-12 07:28:58" "2016-05-12 08:01:56"
```

Comment: V1                  V1.1
1   "2016-05-12 07:28:11" "2016-05-12 07:58:47"
2   "2016-05-12 07:27:39" "2016-05-12 07:58:22"
3   "2016-05-12 07:19:22" "2016-05-12 07:49:40"
4   "2016-05-12 07:15:12" "2016-05-12 07:47:08"
5   "2016-05-12 07:26:44" "2016-05-12 07:58:24"
6   "2016-05-12 07:27:53" "2016-05-12 07:58:33"
7   "2016-05-12 07:20:20" "2016-05-12 07:53:19"
8   "2016-05-12 07:28:58" "2016-05-12 08:01:56"

Comment: If they are both POSIXct vectors then `-` will work _just fine_. Pasting the output of `dput(head(df))` would help (in the question, not as a comment…you should delete your comment, too).

Comment: (1. 30:36) (2. 30:43) (3. 30:18) (4. 31:56) (5. 31:40) (6. 30:40) (7. 32:59) (8. 32:58).  (Hey, you just asked for help calculating, not for help with code to calculate for you!)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know the type or if its a string, its very convenient to use the `lubridate` package, and then you can manipulate the dates with ease after converting them to a format you like. Point in case:

```
df$diff <- ymd_hms(df$date2) - ymd_hms(df$date1)
> df
            date1               date2       dif
1 2016-05-12 07:28:11 2016-05-12 07:58:47 30.6 mins
```

This will create a column with `difftime` class objects. If you want the diff in seconds for example:

```
df$dif <- as.integer((ymd_hms(df$date2) - ymd_hms(df$date1))*60)
> df
            date1               date2  dif
1 2016-05-12 07:28:11 2016-05-12 07:58:47 1836
```

Note that the `ymd_hms()` function is used to parse a string date in the format of year-month-day-hour-minute-second. there are variations for any order, with or without the time.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `as.period` function from the `lubridate` package to do find the time interval of each row. The first two arguments to `mutate` are necessary in order to convert the dates into `POSIXct` objects.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% mutate(V1 = ymd_hms(V1), 
                    V1.1 = ymd_hms(V1.1), 
                    interval = as.period(V1.1 - V1))
```

Be aware that you'll get a warning telling you that it's an `estimate only: convert difftimes to intervals for accuracy`. If you're worried about accuracy, just change the last line to

```
interval = as.period(interval(V1, V1.1))
```

Answer (score -2):

First you have to convert these characters into date class. Run this:

```
for (i in nrow(df)){
    for (j in ncol(df)){
        df[i, j] <- strptime(df[i, j], "%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
    }
}
```

After that, you may subtract col1 and col2 and put the results inside a numeric vector:

```
dif.time.vec <- numeric(length = nrow(df))
for (i in nrow(df)){
    dif.time.vec[i] <- df[i, 2] - df[i, 1]
}
```

Comment: Two of these loops are completely unnecessary, as `strptime` and `-` are vectorized. There are better ways to do the third, e.g. `lapply`.